# Trying to copy from one text file to another in Python

Tags: python, file

I attempted to use the code below, but all I get is that I need exactly 1 argument, but I gave 0.

```
print "Copy one file into another:"

print "Type first file here:" 

file1 = raw_input('>')

openfile = open(file1).read()

file2 = raw_input('>')

open2file = open(file2, 'w')
second = open2file.write() 


print "All Done"
```

Comment: Henceforth please include the Traceback of the error.

Comment: the argument for `write` is whatever you want to put in the output file. `open2file.write("this line goes in the file")`.

Answer (score 3):

It's `open2file.write(openfile)`. This sends the content of the file you read into the opened file.